# Linux Ubuntu is not booting up

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

I am just installing ngspice.
But ./configure fails and then no commands is working except cd
It show command not found errror although PATH is correctly configured
Then I logoff my account and it starts showing authentication error on login screen
And now it is not booting up at all
[Booting error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhwJJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

That screenshot shows a badly corrupted filesystem.

There is no way that configuring and installing `ngspice` (a [Spice circuit simulator](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/)) would have caused this.

It's likely you're going to need to dig out your backups and reinstall. If you don't have backups you're going to lose your data and have to reinstall. Not good, really.